# SSRS report reduces bar width automatically

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, scale, bar-chart

The width of the bar chart throughout the series is automatically reduced to barely visible (for each value) to accommodate the rendering of a large report i.e. extremely long x-axis

Each bar in the report is 1-2 pixels in width and in some cases looks like they are rendered inside each other.[image: Example of problem]

I'm looking to keep the original width of each bar and render a scroll bar instead or something that allows this to be readable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a point of personal interest, displaying too much data in a chart or report detracts from the information it displays. Data and information are completly different. I would want to know what it achieves with this expanded out? :)

Comment: The graph is showing data about an organisations employees. These employees are normally associated with a category but the top manager may want an overview of all employees.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'd make the width of your chart dynamic in that you increase its width based on a count of the columns produced.

I haven't tried this but everthing seems to have an expression ability in report builder.